# How to position activity indicator to the center of its superview using Auto Layout programmatically?

Tags: ios, autolayout, uiactivityindicatorview

Why the following code does not work for positioning activity indicator to the center of its superview:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]
       initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

[self.mysuperview addSubview:activityIndicator];
[activityIndicator addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint 
                   constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"|-(>=20)-[view(==100)]-(>=20)-|"
                   options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX | NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                   metrics:nil
                   views:@{@"view" : self.mysuperview}]];
```

Activity indicator is positioned somewhere at the top left corner, definitely not in the centre.

==================
Update:
FOUND SOLUTION: I have to turn off autoresizing constraints after creating indicator and then all solutions that where given work:

```
 [activityIndicator setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
```

I found it on the link given by @Vignesh, so I accept his/her answer.

Comment: For information, if you use https://github.com/dkduck/FLKAutoLayout then it's handle that for you too.

Comment: I prefer https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry

Comment: Yep. It was translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints for me too. Easy to forget.

Comment: OMG I had the same error.

Comment: See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34621942/1966109) that gives 4 different ways to solve your problem using Auto Layout or Spring and Struts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this,

```
 UIView *superview = self.mysuperview;
NSDictionary *variables = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(activityIndicator, superview);
NSArray *constraints =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[superview]-(<=1)-[activityIndicator]"
                                        options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterX
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:variables];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];

constraints =
[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[superview]-(<=1)-[activityIndicator]"
                                        options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:variables];
[self.view addConstraints:constraints];
```

Taken from [here](https://github.com/evgenyneu/center-vfl).

Comment: thanks for the link, it helped me to found the answer. The solution is [activityIndicator setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

Answer (score 23):

The four following Swift 5 / iOS 12 code samples show how to center a `UIActivityIndicatorView` inside the `UIView` of a `UIViewController` with *Auto layout*.

All samples produce the same result but, according to your needs and tastes, you may choose one or the other.

If your `UIActivityIndicatorView`'s superview is not `self.view`, you simply have to replace each `self.view` call with your own (unwrapped) `superview`.

---

### 1. `NSLayoutConstraint` initializer style

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let indicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        indicatorView.isHidden = false
        indicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(indicatorView)

        // Auto layout
        let horizontalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicatorView,
                                                      attribute: .centerX,
                                                      relatedBy: .equal,
                                                      toItem: self.view,
                                                      attribute: .centerX,
                                                      multiplier: 1,
                                                      constant: 0)
        let verticalConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: indicatorView,
                                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                                    relatedBy: .equal,
                                                    toItem: self.view,
                                                    attribute: .centerY,
                                                    multiplier: 1,
                                                    constant: 0)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
        /*
         // You can replace NSLayoutConstraint activate(_:) call with the following lines:
         self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
         self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
         */
    }

}
```

---

### 2. `UIViewAutoresizing` style

Springs and Struts will be translated into corresponding auto layout constraints at runtime.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let indicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        indicatorView.isHidden = false
        indicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true // default is true
        self.view.addSubview(indicatorView)

        // Springs and struts
        indicatorView.center = CGPoint(x: self.view.bounds.midX, y: self.view.bounds.midY)
        indicatorView.autoresizingMask = [
            .flexibleLeftMargin,
            .flexibleRightMargin,
            .flexibleTopMargin,
            .flexibleBottomMargin
        ]
    }

}
```

---

### 3. Visual Format Language style

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let indicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        indicatorView.isHidden = false
        indicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(indicatorView)

        // Auto layout
        let views = ["superview": self.view!, "indicatorView": indicatorView]
        let horizontalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint
            .constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[superview]-(<=0)-[indicatorView]",
                         options: .alignAllCenterY,
                         metrics: nil,
                         views: views)
        let verticalConstraints = NSLayoutConstraint
            .constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:[superview]-(<=0)-[indicatorView]",
                         options: .alignAllCenterX,
                         metrics: nil,
                         views: views)
        self.view.addConstraints(horizontalConstraints)
        self.view.addConstraints(verticalConstraints)
    }

}
```

---

### 4. `NSLayoutAnchor` style (requires iOS 9)

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let indicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(style: .gray)
        indicatorView.isHidden = false
        indicatorView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(indicatorView)

        // Auto layout
        let horizontalConstraint = indicatorView
            .centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor)
        let verticalConstraint = indicatorView
            .centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([horizontalConstraint, verticalConstraint])
        /*
         // You can replace NSLayoutConstraint activate(_:) call with the following lines:
         self.view.addConstraint(horizontalConstraint)
         self.view.addConstraint(verticalConstraint)
         */
    }

}
```

Comment: The Visual Format Language Style worked for me! Thanks @Imanou Petit

Answer (score 6):

It's meeting it's requirements by being in the corner, since you're not stating that the gaps on each side have to be the same.  Try this instead:

```
[self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:activityIndicator
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                  toItem:self.superview 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
              multiplier:1.0 
                constant:0.0]];
```

And to center vertically do this too:

```
[self.superview addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:activityIndicator
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                  toItem:self.superview 
               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY 
              multiplier:1.0 
                constant:0.0]];
```

Alternatively, I highly recommend using the FLKAutoLayout project to simplify all this:

https://github.com/dkduck/FLKAutoLayout

Then you can do:

```
[activityIndicator alignCenterXWithView:self.superview predicate:nil];
[activityIndicator alignCenterYWithView:self.superview predicate:nil];
```

Which is nice :)

Comment: You need to add `CenterY` also if you want it to be in the center. With only X it can be anywhere on the vertical line in the middle of the superview.

Comment: Yes, but the poster's code was only trying to center horizontally, so I assume that that was the requirement.... Nevertheless I'll update...

Comment: Ah, sorry, I didn't realise that.

Comment: I need actually to center both horizontally and vertically. I don't know what am I doing wrong, but somehow this solution also does not work.

Comment: Check that they have  a common super view.

Comment: Actually the superview of activity indicator is mysuperview, which is the view to where I am trying to add the constraint as it is described in your example. So I have such a hierarchy mysuperview -> activityIndicator, mysuperview -> add centre constraint. Or it is not correct?

Comment: Try [superview layoutIfNeeded]

Answer (score 0):

I centered my activity indicator in its superview by adding it in Interface Builder with an alpha of zero (and an IBOutlet for it in my view controller class).  Then I added constraints to center it in the X and Y axes.  Finally, I added width and height constraints to it to silence an autolayout error.

In my view controller's startActivityIndicator method, I set the alpha of the activity indicator to one and call the startAnimating method on it.  In my stopActivityIndicator method, I call the stopAnimating method on it and set the alpha of the activity indicator back to zero.