# XIB: Centering elements

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib

I have an XIB file containing a simple activity indicator that I want to be vertically and horizontally centered. In XCode I can center it in `w:compact` and `h:compact`, but when I run it on the device its not centered (is offset). I have searched and I found suggestions on constraints or disabling auto layout, but when I do any of these my activity indicator is not shown in the view anymore.
I'd appreciate if you can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: had you use auto layout?

Comment: Yes , auto layout is checked , but when I remove it , no elements is shown

Comment: i mean to say....did you give any constraints to your controllers?

Comment: No, and when I do, also nothing is shown

Comment: check this link.. ...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29484522/horizontal-center-constraint-issue-in-ios/29485222#29485222  or check this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19431286/how-to-position-activity-indicator-to-the-center-of-its-superview-using-auto-lay

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add Activity indicator and select it and add constraints like in image.

[image: Autolayout constaraints]

**P.S** - Learning curve of auto layout is very tricky and require patience. The more you practice, more you improve. Read online tutorials, youth videos..Implement!

Comment: Thanks I also added width and height constraints , I don't know if they were required though!

Comment: No i dont think you need to set those, coz indicator has fixed size. You can increase its size programatically though.

Answer (score 1):

if you use auto layout,you must add all constraints for the view. 
You must define the width,the height,the horizontal and vertical location of the view.
Or you can just not use auto layout,set the frame of the view programatically like

```
  theView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(self.view.frame.width/2 - theView.frame.size.width/2,self.view.frame.size.height/2 - theView.frame.size.height/2)
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a beginner in iOS development. I have my UI design in w:compact h:compact. and when click "Add Missing Constraints" it just adds Center Y alignment and Center X Alignment.

Comment: @m0j1  you may try to set the width and height constraint. Or you can log the frame of you view after viewDidLayoutSubviews:  and find what's wrong.And you should make sure the view of xib(the superview of activity indicator)'s layout is correct .

Comment: The way to go is to use autolayout constraints.

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting constraints in w:compact h:compact only, then it would only show in iPhones in landscape (except iphone 6+). Try adding the constraints in w:any h:any, which is where your base layout should be. It should work with any screen size or orientation.

You can also Debug View Hierarchy during debugging if you can't see some of your views:

[image]